# CSS : Rotate an element without rotating its inner content - Single Element

Tags: css, rotation, transform

I am trying to build the flag of Bosnia and Herzegovina which looks like this.

[image: http://flags.fmcdn.net/data/flags/normal/ba.png]

I am trying to achieve how the stars are lined up. They are laid on a 45deg tilted axis but the stars themselves aren't rotated.

The following is the bare minimum code I am trying but it rotates the stars too.

Is there a way to avoid it?

P.S - I am not allowed to add another element to DOM.

```css
.flag {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.flag::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '★★★★★★★★★';
  color: black;
  font-size: 3rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.33rem;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flag"></div>
```

Comment: I would recommend using each star as a single dom element, then wrap it in a div, rotate the div and rotate back only the stars. Ah, sorry didn't see that you can't add any dom element. That sucks. I will let you know if I figure something out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better idea: use `text-shadow`! Basic CSS:

```css
div {
  font-size: 5em;
  text-shadow: .5em .5em, 1em 1em, 1.5em 1.5em, 2em 2em, 2.5em 2.5em, 3em 3em, 3.5em 3.5em, 4em 4em;
}
```

```html
<div>★</div>
```

---

## Original idea

Kind of ugly, but you could put tabs between the stars, then use a `ch`-valued `font-size` and play with `tab-size` and `line-height`. Basic idea:

```css
.star {
 font: 6.5ch/.5 monospace;
 tab-size: .75ch;
}
```

```html
<pre class='star'>★
 ★
  ★
   ★
    ★
     ★
      ★
       ★
        ★</pre>
```

## [*`quick attempt at the actual flag`*](https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/Lxwype/)

Note that it only seems to work in Chrome. ☹

Comment: That'll be a solution but many points to break. I wish there was something in css transforms to do this natively. :( I am gonna try this one anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.flag {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.flag-star:before {
  font-size: 3rem;
  content:"★";
  display: inline-block;
}

.deg-1{
  transform: rotate(47deg);
}
.deg-2{
  transform: rotate(48deg);
}
.deg-3{
  transform: rotate(49deg);
}
.deg-4{
  transform: rotate(50deg);
}
.deg-5{
  transform: rotate(51deg);
}
.deg-6{
  transform: rotate(52deg);
}
.deg-7{
  transform: rotate(53deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flag">
    <div class="flag-star deg-1"></div>
    <div class="flag-star deg-2"></div>
    <div class="flag-star deg-3"></div>
    <div class="flag-star deg-4"></div>
    <div class="flag-star deg-5"></div>
    <div class="flag-star deg-6"></div>
    <div class="flag-star deg-7"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I mentioned i can't add more elements to DOM.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Rotate .flag::before two time first 45deg then 170deg.

```css
.flag {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
.flag::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '★★★★★★★★★';
  color: black;
  font-size: 2rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.33rem;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg) rotate(170deg);
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flag"></div>
```

Comment: what that would do is rotate the entire flag. The flag should stay how it is.. it's the array of stars that should rotate.

Comment: @PraveenPuglia Then you have to rotate .flag::before two times.

Comment: Amazing. Can you explain why it works? I have a guess but let's see if that's it :D

Comment: The second rotate will rotate it 170deg from the 45deg angle (you're just flipping it vertically). rotate(45deg) rotate(170deg) == rotate(215deg), but the first one is easy to understand.

Comment: I realized it doesn't really work as expected. The additional rotation seems to be working because of the nature of a star shape. Thanks though.